# Excel Formula Sum if greater than 0 in Column A and Column B equals text

Tags: microsoft-excel

If Column A has a specific text, I want to sum column B if greater than zero.

For example, If I collect fees and then someone asks for a refund then that fee becomes a wash.  I don't want to delete that refund because I want to track the transaction. So I understand to use:

```
=sumif(B1:B10,">0")
```

Where I get stumped is that I want to sum column B if greater than zero and column A contains fiscal year "18-19".

I was able to create this formula

```
=sumif(A1:A10,"*18-19*",B1:B10)
```

How would I write this formula to include if greater than 0?

Comment: Look into [`SUMIFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)  It allows the use of multiple criteria.   But note that the order of criteria is different in SUMIFS than it is in SUMIF

Comment: Maybe you could try `=SUMIFS(B1:B10,B1:B10,">0",A1:A10,"=*18-19*")`